# Calculate length of custom data

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell one day at a time. At this time, I'd like to capture the size of a custom data to process it further. Say I have:

```
data LetterAlphabet = L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 deriving (Show,Enum,Bounded)

fun :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> Int
fun a = 1 + fromEnum (maxBound :: LetterAlphabet)
```

It works but I had to indicated the data type explicitly. I tried to use (maxBound :: typeof a) and similars, with no success.

Comment: Beware: `Enum` does not promise that its constituents correspond to contiguous `Int`s or that they start at 0. For example, `fun :: Int8 -> Int` will return 127 even though there are 256 `Int8`s because 0 is not the smallest `Int8`. For non-contiguous `Enum`s, one can look to FFI bindings that wrap C bitfields, for example. `Double` is another example of weirdness (one could in principle use ±∞ to make a `Bounded` instance). For a more targeted approach, consider using [`cardinality`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.3/docs/Data-Universe-Class.html#t:Finite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a trick by using [**`asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:asTypeOf) which returns the first item but forces that the item is of the same type as the second parameter, so:

```
fun :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> Int
fun a = 1 + fromEnum (asTypeOf maxBound a)
```

But a more elegant way is to work with the [**`TypeApplications`** extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html#extension-TypeApplications):

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

fun :: forall a . (Bounded a, Enum a) => Int
fun = 1 + fromEnum (maxBound @a)
```

Then this can be used as `fun @LetterAlphabet`). We thus only specify the type, we do not pass a variable of that type.